# how to get this code into a access form as text label?

Tags: ms-access

I found this code on the internet but I don't know how to display this code on the access 2010 form.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
Dim strPin As String 
Dim i As Integer 

strPin = "JobNr" 

'Set seed 
Call Randomize 

For i = 1 To 4 
   strPin = strPin & Int(10 * Rnd) 
Next
```

Question edit:

I have this, pls don't look at the markup, it's just a test.

```
Private Sub Tekst49_Click()
Dim strPin As String
Dim i As Integer

strPin = "JobNr: "

'Set seed
Call Randomize

For i = 1 To 5
   strPin = strPin & Int(10 * Rnd)
Next

Me.Tekst49 = strPin
End Sub
```

As the private sub says, it's a onclick event.
Can someone tell  me if BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate means after inserting a new record?
Because that's what I like to have, a number which is generated on form load and after starting a new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display the value, create a text box and do something like the following

```
For i = 1 To 4 
    strPin = strPin & Int(10 * Rnd) 
Next
me.myTextBox = strPin
```

You could do the same with a label as well:

```
me.mylabel.caption = strPin
```

Answer (score 0):

What is it you want to achieve?
The VBA code as it stands would create "JobNr[randomnumber]" e.g. "`JobNr8123`".

`Rnd()` creates a random number between 0 and 1 and the expression `Int(10 * Rnd)` creates a random number between 0 and 10 (to be exact it is a random number between 0 and 9.99999 which would always come down to 9). As this is iterated over 4 times, the random number becomes actually 4 digits - this could have been done easier with `Int(1000 * Rnd)` with the same effect.

Comment: Actually, the loop does not overwrite `strPin` as it's concatenating each time. All that's being done is generating four random digits and appending them to the initial string. Why this can't be done with a single call to Rnd() and multiple by 1000 and pad with leading zeroes, I haven't a clue.

Comment: Wouldn't `Int(10 * Rnd)` create a random number between 0 (not 1) and 9.99 (and then convert it to int)?

Comment: Thank you all, I have edied my question, can someone tell me how a new random number is generated before and after a new record?